# what does v('APP_ID') return in oracle apex when you are in the SQL commands area?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to understand what v('APP_ID') returns when I am in the SQL commands area. When I call it from an APEX page it returns the APP_ID correctly. However, when in SQL commands it is returning the value 4500 that is not any app_id in my workspace.

`select * from apex_applications where application_id = 4500;`

This SQL returns nothing.

Thank you in advance.

I am expecting the function to return null in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function v('APP_ID') returns the application id value of the session.
So in your example, it returns the application id of the SQL commands which means it is the application id of your Oracle Apex instance.
Oracle Apex itself is also an Oracle Apex application. That is why it has a application ID but it is internal to Oracle so you can not get any result by that query.

Comment: ok, so it is what I imagined. In my case I will show null when is not a "valid" apex_application.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `apex_applications` script (quite a lot of code, over 600 lines for Apex 20.2), you'll see its

- `FROM` clause (www_flow_current_workspaces might be *crucial*)
- `WHERE` clause which filters data we see
- `COMMENTS`; the one that describes `apex_applications` answers your question:

  > Applications defined in the **current workspace** or **database user**

[image]

As of `v('APP_ID')`:

- when you call it from Apex page, it returns `ID` of the current application (that's expected/obvious)
- when you call it from SQL Workshop, it returns `4500` which is ID of Apex (application) itself; that's because SQL Workshop is a "common" *utility*, isn't related to any particular application you created